# How can I resolve an INSERT statement conflict with a CHECK constraint in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I get this error:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 105
> The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK__Orders__Order_St__33D4B598". The conflict occurred in database "Online_Sales", table "dbo.Orders", column 'Order_Status'.

I tried inserting data into a table in SQL Server, when I got this error.

Comment: According to the database schema (in this case specifically the constraint `CK__Orders__Order_St__33D4B598`), the data being inserted is invalid.  So you'd either modify the schema to allow this data, or use valid data.

Comment: Likely the Order_Status is some sort of code that is expected to be in a defined set of values for different order states and you entered a value that is not one of these pre-defined valid states

Answer (score 1):

There is a check constraint defined on the table that, essentially, says "you can't insert data unless you pass these rules." You need to determine what those rules (the check constraint's definition) are, and make sure your data can pass that test.

There are ways to drill down in SSMS to find these rules. Another alternative is to query the system tables, which is what I generally do--but only because I have access to a bunch of support scripts, accumulated over the years. Below is one that should help you find the code in question.

```
SELECT
   sc.name   [Schema (CKs)]
  ,taP.name  [Table]
  ,cc.name   CheckName
  ,case when col.name is null then '...' else col.name end  [Col or Tbl]
  ,cc.is_disabled
  ,cc.is_not_trusted
  ,cc.definition
 from sys.check_constraints  cc
  inner join sys.tables  taP
   on taP.object_id = cc.parent_object_id
  inner join sys.schemas sc
   on sc.schema_id = taP.schema_id
  left outer join sys.columns  col
   on col.object_id = taP.object_id
    and col.column_id = cc.parent_column_id
 --where sc.name = '??'
 -- and taP.Name = '??'
```

Comment: One can also use `sp_help '«table name»';` to get all sorts of information about the table including constraints. Your solution is more targeted/precise but for quick examination of a table's schema, `sp_help` wins on speed.